# JTable.getValueAt(i, 0) is null when te cell have a JeditorPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jeditorpane

I'm using a `JEditorPane` and `JscrollPane` as a cell renderer in my table (so I can control color, font, size and links easily). the problem is that I can't reach the content of the cell with :

```
for (int i = 0; i < detalle_jTable.getRowCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println((String) JTable.getValueAt(i, 3));
}
```

the problem is that lines always return `null`.
Here is my `tableCellrender` and `tablecellEditor` code:

```
class celdaScrollCellRender extends JTextPane implements TableCellRenderer {

    JScrollPane scroll2 ;
    JEditorPane areaDeTexto;

    public celdaScrollCellRender() {
        areaDeTexto = new JEditorPane();
        scroll2 = new JScrollPane(areaDeTexto);     
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, 
    boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {  
        return scroll2;   
    }
}//de la clase

///////////////////////////////**********************************/////
class celdaScrollEditor extends JTextPane implements TableCellEditor {  
    JEditorPane areaDeTexto;
    JScrollPane scroll2;

    //constructor
    public celdaScrollEditor() {
        areaDeTexto = new JEditorPane();
        scroll2 = new JScrollPane(areaDeTexto);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table,Object value,boolean isSelected,int row, int column) {
        areaDeTexto.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        areaDeTexto.setSize(560, 60);        
        areaDeTexto.setContentType("text/html");
        areaDeTexto.setText((String) value);        

        return scroll2; 
    }

    @Override
    public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {  
       //solo muestra el contenido al hacer un clic por primera vez
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelCellEditing() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {  
        return areaDeTexto.getText();        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        return true;
    }   
}  //de la clase
```

And in the tablemodel:

```
detalle_jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(new celdaScrollCellRender());
detalle_jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellEditor(new celdaScrollEditor());
```

Comment: What is `getColumnClass` for the column 3 returning. AFAIK `JEditorPane` or what ever component is used to render the data on `Table`. But the `TableModel` still contains the actual data. So get the model and from the model get the data.

Comment: System.out.println(detalle_jTable.getColumnClass(3));                   //Its print: class java.lang.Object

Comment: 1) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: How i get the data from the class java.lang.Object?